# Can´t get second to last li of ul from Instagram Follower with Phantomjs through node-horseman

Tags: phantomjs, node-horseman

this is my first quest here. I search for the Problem and haven´t found an answer yet so i hope someone here is able to give me a hint.

The Situation is as follows:
I use node-horseman 3.1.1 to retrieve my follower from Instagram.

My Workflow is login, open my user, open popover of my followers. That works fine, i have seen the html sourcecode and screenshots that proof that everything is working.

Then i try to get the list of followers from an ul with several li´s. I can access the first li, but not the others.
I tried:

```
horseman
        .evaluate(function (done) {
            var result = {li:[], length: 0};

            var followerList = $("ul._539vh._4j13h");
            followerList.each(function (i, el) {
                result.push(el);
            });
            //or
            var followerList = document.getElementsByClassName("_cx1ua");
            followerList.children().each(function (i, el) {
                result.push(el);
            });
            // Also tried CSS Selectors:
            // Iterate over li´s
            // ul._539vh._4j13h children
            // div._a1rcs children
            // li._cx1ua siblings
            // a._4zhc5.notranslate._j7lfh siblings

            done(null, result);}.then(function (Link) {


            console.log('A:' + Link + ' Length: ' + Link.length);

            var children = Link.childNodes;
            for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                // do something with each child as children[i]
                // NOTE: List is live, Adding or removing children will change the list
                console.log("i:" + children[i]);
            }
```

The 1st version outputs an array length 0 and the first li with it´s data. The 2nd version outputs an empty array.

Then i tried:

```
horseman
        .evaluate(function (done) {
            var result = {li:[], length: 0};

            var Link = document.evaluate("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/ul", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;Link.children = [];
            for (var i = 8; i < 9;i++) {
                result.length += 1;
                li = document.evaluate("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/ul/li", document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);
                li.children = null;
                result.li.push(li);
            }}
```

But that gives me also just the 1st Li and that is also incomplete.

I also tried to return the ul element and iterate later about the lis but that gave me just an empty array.
Returning the first li and trying to iterate it´s siblings also failed.

What am i doing wrong? I found some threads that indicated problems in phantomjs with ocument.evaluate("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/ul/li", document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null); .

I know Selenium can do what i need but it needs to start Firefox or Chrome with a Visible GUI Instance. That blocks other activities and is Resource intense.

Does someone know an alternative Method? Scraping seems is impossible afaik because Instagram Blocks Access to the Follower and Following list while the accessing user is not logged in.

Kind Regards,
Frank